# set groupable option dynamically in KendoUI grid with angular doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I want to create a toggle button thats add/remove groupable option in my KENDO grid. In initialize i have not property 'groupable'.

```
{
        type: "button",
        togglable: true,
        id: "groupableToggle",
        toggle: function (e) {
            var grid = $("#grid" + config.id).data("kendoGrid");
            if (e.checked) {
                grid.options.groupable = {
                  messages: {
                     empty: "drag a column header and drop it here to group by that column"
                  }
                };                    
            }
            else 
              grid.options.groupable = false

            grid._thead();
            grid.refresh();
        }
    }
```

but this is not work!

OK!! I FOUND IT!

```
              if (e.checked) {
                grid.setOptions({
                    groupable: true,
                    messages: {
                        empty: "drag a column header and drop it here to group by that column"
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                grid.setOptions({
                    groupable: false
                });
            }


            grid._thead();
            grid.refresh();
```

and now plays

Answer (score 0):

The `groupable` setting cannot be changed on the fly without recreating the Grid. Use the `setOptions` method of the Grid, or `k-rebind` to achieve that.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/widget#methods-setOptions

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#widget-update-upon-option-changes

Comment: if (e.checked) {
                    grid.setOptions({
                        groupable: true,
                        messages: {
                            empty: "drag a column header and drop it here to group by that column"
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    grid.setOptions({
                        groupable: false
                    });
                }


                grid._thead();
                grid.refresh();

Comment: There is no need to call _thead() or refresh() after setOptions().